# Bean to csv with optional column

Tags: java, opencsv

How to convert my bean `MyClassCsv` to a CSV file with the name of an optional column? The column 'title' must be contained or not in the CSV file.

The bean:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyClassCsv implements Serializable {
   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6476622625063619084L;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "name")
    private String name; 
    
    @CsvBindByName(column = "title")
    private String title; 
    
    ...
}
```

Write to CSV:

```
final Writer writer = new FileWriter(fileCsv.getPath());

try {
    final HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<HoteIncbCsv> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
    strategy.setType(MyClassCsv.class);

    // **** optional mapped 'title'  ***** //
    if (!useTitle) {
        // ?????????
    }
    
    final StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).withMappingStrategy(strategy).withSeparator(';').withApplyQuotesToAll(false).build();

    // Ecriture dans le fichier CSV de sortie
    beanToCsv.write(myClassCsv);

} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old post , but stumbled upon it while doing something similar, maybe somebody would need solution.
`HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy`  has  `setIgnoredFields` method that can be used in exactly that case.
You can create more or less something like this to create strategy

```java
private HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy <MyClassCsv> createHeaderStrategy(boolean title) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<MyClassCsv >();
    strategy.setType(MyClassCsv.class);
    if(!title){
        MultiValuedMap<Class<?>, Field> ignore = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<Class<?>, Field>();
        ignore.put(MyClassCsv.class, MyClassCsv.class.getDeclaredField("title")) 
        strategy.ignoreFields(ignore);
    }
    return strategy 
}
```

This of course can be done better with some custom annotations to exclude more fields if needed, and eliminate need of potentially catching NoSuchFieldException exception.